# How to authorize a kafka principal for a consumer group that is not named

Tags: apache-kafka, authorization, kafka-consumer-api

I am receiving such errors in kafka authorizer log:

```
[2019-11-05 09:19:27,050] INFO Principal = User:CN=***,OU=***,O=*** is Denied Operation = Read from host = *** on resource = Group:LITERAL: (kafka.authorizer.logger)
```

The problem is that I don't know how to authorize the principal, considering the fact that the group name it tries to use is empty. 
I tried with using asterisk *, that created an ACL for a resource named contoller.log, and it didn't help, second try was to place a blank there ' ', but that resulted in such error:

```
Error while executing ACL command: Path must not end with / character
```

although it tried to add the ACL for intended resource:

```
Adding ACLs for resource `Group:LITERAL:`:
```

This also doesn't work because of the same error:

```
kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --allow-principal User:*** --operation Read -add --group '' --resource-pattern-type prefixed
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have access to the consumer? can you check its `group.id`?  I have feeling there's a white space in the group name that you miss...

Comment: OK, is it possible to create an ACL for a group name consisting of white spaces only? If not, then trying to use such is equally problematic as not setting group.id at all. Right?

Comment: I don't know whether it lets you to have whitespace or not. Maybe there's a bug in the code, but what I meant if you have access to the consumer config fix the group.id to sth meaningful, and if you do not have access to it, and you are on the server admin for Kafka, communicate with the consumers, and clarify it. Instead of trying to set an ACL which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Of course, I already did that, just wanted to be sure there is no way to create such an ACL, as it makes no sense.